# How can I achieve this TextField?

Tags: flutter

Picture of textfield:
[image: pic of textfield]

You can ignore the "First Name" label at the top, and the error label at the bottom. I've tried to make the TextField look like in the pic, but I'm not sure how to make the prefix icon be at the left edge, and I also don't know how to make the line of the TextField thicker.

Comment: You can create all those effect with [InputDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this behaviour you need to add a decoration to your TextField.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person), //This is the icon 
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: 
                      const BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 4.0)) //Width is the thickness
));
```

I am sure you can figure the rest our by yourself by looking at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html). The Border is a tricky one but the rest should be pretty intuitive and understandable.